# Unable to select dropdown values through protractor

Tags: protractor

I'm unable to select drop down values through protractor.
Below is the drop down code.

```
<select kendo-drop-down-list="dropDownControl" k-ng-model="value" 
        k-options="options" ng-disabled="readOnly=='true'" 
        class="ppKendoDropDown" w6set-kendo-combo-items-width="" 
        data-role="dropdownlist" style="display: none;">
   <option value="-1">Not Defined</option>
   <option value="541999104" selected="selected">Region1</option>
   <option value="542007296">test region</option>
</select>
```

Below is the complete div

```
 <div html-compile="keyControlTemplate"><w6-drop-down value="valueObject" property-name="propertyName" model-controller="ngModel" options="options" strings="strings" state="state" key-data-service="dataService" related-object-name="relatedObjectName" display-property-name="displayPropertyNameValue" sort-property-name="sortPropertyNameValue" default-value="defaultValue" filter-items="filterItems" filter-operation="filterOperation" related-parent-property="relatedParentProperty" parent-value="parentValue" ng-readonly="readOnly" mandatory="mandatory" change="onChange()" ng-class="{'error-input': formSubmitted &amp;&amp;  ngModel.$invalid }" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope" readonly="readonly">
  <span title="" class="k-widget k-dropdown k-header ppKendoDropDown" unselectable="on" role="listbox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-owns="" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" style="" aria-busy="false" aria-activedescendant="418efbdc-cf62-43db-9a45-6d465ebe53ea">
     <span unselectable="on" class="k-dropdown-wrap k-state-default"><span unselectable="on" class="k-input ng-scope">Not Defined</span><span unselectable="on" class="k-select"><span unselectable="on" class="k-icon k-i-arrow-s">select</span></span></span>
     <select kendo-drop-down-list="dropDownControl" k-ng-model="value" k-options="options" ng-disabled="readOnly=='true'" class="ppKendoDropDown" w6set-kendo-combo-items-width="" data-role="dropdownlist" style="display: none;">
        <option value="-1">Not Defined</option>
        <option value="541999104">Region1</option>
        <option value="542007296">test region</option>
     </select>
  </span></w6-drop-down></div>
```

Protractor code:

```
element.all(by.options('options')).get(1).click();
```

I want to select option Region1 by index value but getting below error

> Failed: Index out of bound. Trying to access element at index: 1, but
>   there are only 0 elements that match locator by.option("options")

Appreciate your help.

Comment: The dropdown is not visible, because it's set to `style="display: none;"`. I think you not give the correct or the entire HTML code for your dropdown.

Comment: seems your dropdown used Kendo UI, I get a demo url at here https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/index.  Look at the dropdown for CAP SIZE, which is similar your case.

Comment: After you click on the dropdown, the options will expand and display out. But these options not comes from the <option> of invisible <select>.  Actually they comes from a DIV (<div class="k-animation-container" ) near the bottom of the page source.  So you should click the option from the DIV, not from the Select

Comment: Your given code not includes the visible options after you click the dropdown.

Comment: Thanks @yong, I will test again.

Answer (score 0):

From Protractor's documentation of `by.options`:

> Find an element by ng-options expression.

You don't have an `ng-option` attribute here.

Of course, it could be done in another way:

```
var dropdown = element(by.css('.ppKendoDropDown'))
var opt = dropdown.all(by.css('option')).get(1)

dropdown.click()
opt.click()
```

Comment: Thanks @yong but it did not work.
Error:  Failed: element not interactable
      (Session info: chrome=70.0.3538.110)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.43.600210 (68dcf5eebde37173d4027fa8635e332711d2874a),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)

Comment: As I added comment under your question, the dropdown is not visible, so selenium report `element not interactable`.  You not give correct HTML code of your dropdown.

Comment: I've edit the question with complete div, can you please look now @yong

Answer (score 0):

#### Try this:

first, you should click the drop-down to open it.

```
 dropdown=element(by.css('select.ppKendoDropDown'))
 dropdown.click();
 selectDropdownbynum(dropdown,2)


 selectDropdownbyNum(element, optionNum) {
        if (optionNum) {
            element.all(by.tagName('option')).then(function(options) {
                options[optionNum].click();
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select them as this

```
element(by.id('option id')).sendKeys('option value');
 element(by.xpath('//*[@id="option id"]/option[index]')).click();
 element(by.cssContainingText('option','value')).click();
```

this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Your dropdown used Kendo UI, its a css & javascript dropdown, not a native dropdown.

For most css & javascript dropdown, the options not comes from the invisible `select` node, it usually comes from `ul` node under other element.

```
// click on dropdown to expand options
element(by.css('span.ppKendoDropDown')).click();

// or choose option by text
element(by.xpath('//ul/li[@class="k-item"][text()="test region"]')).click();
```